# Eliminating the need to write 'this' inside function being called by call()?

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to write expressions as strings and then evaluate them. So I have:

```
var expression  = "this.num*2"
function x(expression, o) {
  var fn = function(){}, result;
  fn = Function.apply(o, ["return " + expression + " ;"]);
  return fn.call(o)
}

var obj = {"num":3}
console.log(x(expression, obj))
```

Which works great. However, I want to be able to write "num*2"

How do I do this?

Comment: You can't do that.  (unless you use `with`, which is even more evil than the `eval` you're already using)

Comment: i had a function builder where there is a shortcut that if the string starts with ".", then it replaces "." with "this.", would that work? `expression=expression.replace(/^\./g,"this.")` if you cache the resulting function (same strings will produce same output), you can actually end up with a faster-executing function than hard-coding it (no closures and stuff).

Comment: Is there a safe way to do this? How do web apps for testing code like codepen or jsfiddle do it safely?

Comment: there's nothing unsafe about how you were doing it...

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [JavaScript Expression Evaluation library](http://silentmatt.com/javascript-expression-evaluator/), which allows doing things like `Parser.evaluate("num * 2", {num: 3})`.